# Box2d bodys won't center in screen when using Pixel per meter

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I am trying to create a sample circle to test the pixel per meter.

My PPM is set to 100.
Height and width was set to 320 and 480

Do you why It won't center in y axis but it will center in x axis. also when I set the radius to 50 it doens't draw anything.  Am I missing something here?

```
 this.world = new World(new Vector2(0.0f, -9.8f), true);

        BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        bodyDef.position.set(  App.WIDTH / 2 / PPM, App.HEIGHT / 2 / PPM);
        bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;

        Body body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

        FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        CircleShape shape = new CircleShape();
        shape.setRadius(100 / PPM);
        fixtureDef.shape = shape;

        body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
        shape.dispose();
        player = new Player(body);

        box2DDebugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
        box2dCam = new OrthographicCamera();


        box2dCam.setToOrtho(false, App.WIDTH / PPM  ,  App.HEIGHT / PPM  );
```

When Radius is 100, when radius is 50 the screen is just plain black

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind guys.

`shape.setRadius((float) 20 / PPM);` I had to cast it to float to show all lower than 100

PPM was declared int should be float to avoid casting.

to center it on screen

```
box2dCam.position.set(App.WIDTH / 2 / PPM, App.HEIGHT / 2 / PPM, 0);
```